# What's a typical lifetime for excitons, or biexcitons?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, quasiparticles

I've read that a typical lifetime for [excitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton) in a semiconductor is 1-10 picoseconds.  I believe these are [Wannier-Mott excitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton#Wannier%E2%80%93Mott_exciton).

What are typical lifetimes of other kinds of excitons, for example in carbon nanotubes?   How about [biexcitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biexciton)?